# Dynamic Form Creation

Tags: delphi

I create my forms at runtime something like this:

```
AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(AboutForm);
try
  AboutForm.ShowModal;
finally
  AboutForm.Free;
end;
```

But what is the difference though in using any of these:

```
AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(Self);
AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(nil);
AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(Application);
```

They all seem to work the same from what I can see but which is correct, or are they all correct, which is generally the best one to use?

Appreciate your comments thanks :)

Comment: 1. Your first example doesn't have a memory leak.

Comment: re: your now deleted question on how to be a good programmer - read the fine manual before dispatching the question to the public - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TCustomForm.Create . Which argument is of special interest for you? Yes, `AOwner` - follow the link - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TComponent.Owner

Comment: @user539484 thanks, I thought my other deleted question would of been allowed as it was a programming related question.

Comment: AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(AboutForm) is **very** wrong, because AboutForm is not initialized when passed to the constructor. If it contains something else but NIL, your application might crash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The TForm.Create takes an `Owner` as parameter.

In your first example, `AboutForm` is the owner.  Which obviously is a bad idea, since it's not created yet.

When `Self` is the parameter, the instance that makes the call is the owner.
When `Application` is the parameter, the Application is the owner.
When `nil` is the parameter, the AboutForm doen not have a owner.  That is all fine, but in those cases you must remember to free the form yourself.

When you do pass in a owner, you actually don't need to free i explicitly.  The owner will free it when the owner is freed.

**This is how your code should look like:**

```
AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(nil);
try
  AboutForm.ShowModal;
finally
  AboutForm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: That makes sense, especially with the information @PresleyDias posted.

Comment: Take also a look at this atricle that describes the Owner- and component notification-system, and why you souldn't assign an owner to a component that you intend to free yourself: http://delphi.about.com/od/kbcurt/ss/dynamiccreateno.htm

Comment: Great thanks, I can see now how passing the wrong parameter is a bad thing!

Answer (score 5):

when you create the Form dynamically, that is the form is `available` form.
You have to Pass the `owner` of the form.

[image]

..
So in your case

> AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(Self);
>
> AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(nil);
>
> AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(Application);

1. Self
2. Nil
3. Application

is the owner of the for `AboutForm` (as you already may know it)

`But what is the difference though in using any of these:`

here is something from  [about.com-Form Owner](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/nilselfapp.htm)

> **nil** - specifies that no object owns the form - and therefore a developer (you) is responsible for freeing the created form (by calling myForm.Free when you no longer need the form)
>
> **Self** - specifies the object in which the method is called. If, for example, you are creating a new instance of a TMyForm form from inside a Button's OnClick handler (where this button is placed on a MainForm) - self refers to "MainForm". Thus, when the MainForm is freed - it will also free "MyForm".
>
> **Application** - specifies a global TApplication type variable created when you run your application. "Application" encapsulates your application as well as providing many functions that occur in the background of the program.

and this also [Form Owner](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1467492)

> a)Formx.Create(Application) -> Form resources will be freed when application is terminated
>
> b)Formx.Create(Self) -> Form resources are freed when the owner object is destroyed (if Self is a descendand of TComponent)
>
> c)Formx.Create(nil) -> you are responsible for freeing the form.

This is from

> **a** is used by delphi when a form is autocreated
>
> **b** is handy for a main form that has several child windows that need to close when the main form is closed
>
> **c** is handy for showing a dialog window

For freeing you can do this `ACtion := caFree` onclose of the form.

Answer (score 2):

The first one

```
AboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(AboutForm);
```

tells the TAboutForm, that it's Owner is an object, which has been assigned to the pointer "AboutForm" before (could also be NIL -> no Owner).

The "Owner" parameter of

```
TForm.Create(Owner: TComponent)
```

tells the form, who is it's owner. TComponents register themselves at their owner, if some is provided. So, there is some kind of communication between the owner and it's childs.

Example: If the owner gets freed, he can free it's owned components also.

Therefore,

```
TAboutForm.Create(Self);
```

means, that "Self" is the Owner of the new TAboutForm, if `(Self is TComponent)`.

```
TAboutForm.Create(NIL);
```

is also an acceptable solution, but here, you have to free the component yourself (except for, you create TAboutForm within a MDI-Window).

Comment: How do you think the first one could be right? Under what circumstances should one TAboutForm create and own another TAboutForm, and then discard the reference to the original and replace it with the new one?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Ok, the first one could be right! Of course, there could be created another TControl and assigned to AboutForm, before it is overriden with the new ObjRef. I read it the wrong way round (it was a little late here in austria ;)

Comment: @RobKennedy your comment above makes a lot of sense when you put it like that :)